# Trouble understanding global variables in python -- A logger

Tags: python, codec

So I've been trying to unsuccessfully build a logger for a python program. Here is what I wrote down (Edit: the first while is redundant as pointed out, here is what I have written now)

```
def logger():

    global logmsg

    with codecs.open(LOGFILE, "a+", encoding='utf-8') as write_obj:
        writer = csv.writer(write_obj, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        while True:
            if(logmsg != ""):
                writer.writerow(logmsg)
                logmsg = ""
```

Now this is being referenced by a bunch of other functions as a global variable (the logmsg variable) For example here: (which is an exerpt from another function):

```
def someotherFunc():
    global logmsg
    global message
    global user

....
# lots of code
....
                        if (currentTime - timeLastPosted) > MASTERTIMEDELAY:
                            # Set all the messages and stuff
                            message = getMessage(line)
                            TimeDelayMaps[user] = currentTime
                            # log the message 
                            logmsg = [user, message, str(currentTime), "allowed", "twitch"]
                            print(user + " : " + message)
                        else:
                            logmsg = [user, message, str(currentTime), "not allowed"]
                            ErrorMessage = user + " please wait for " + str(currentTime - timeLastPosted) + " seconds"
                            sendMessage(irc, ErrorMessage)
                            print(user + " tried to post before time was up")
```

or another shorter function:

```
def websock():

    async def WebSocketserver(websocket, path):
    
        global message
        global logmsg
    
        while True:
            try: 
                Rxdata = await websocket.recv()
                # construct the message that we will log
                data = json.loads(Rxdata)
                command = data.get('Message')
                person = data.get('Name')
                commandTime = data.get('Time')
                message = command
                logmsg = [person, message, str(commandTime), "allowed", "console"]
                print(f" {person} on the controller: {command}")
                await websocket.send("200")
            except Exception:
                pass

    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

    start_server = websockets.serve(WebSocketserver, Host, SocketPort)

    loop.run_until_complete(start_server)
    loop.run_forever()
```

edit: I'm also starting up a thread and running the logger service on it like so:

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target=someotherFunc)
t1.start()
t2 = threading.Thread(target=websoc)
t2.start()
# t3' s thread
t4 = threading.Thread(target=logger)
t4.start()
```

now, according to me whenever new log message is logged - the logger should detect that and then set the logmsg to "" and log the line using the writer -- but that is not happening - its creating the file but not logging anything - why is that ?

Comment: You have two nested `while True` loops in `logger` without showing any break statement, and you don't call it asynchronously. I don't believe `logger()` will ever exit as a result. Instead, you should define `logger` to take a message as an argument, and then just write that to the log file. We also don't see you declare `global logmsg` in your excerpt, nor do we see you call `logger()` there.

Comment: Hello - so I did make a threaded call -on thread 4 (edited that in) The globals are declared ... the method was just wayyy to long for me to copy paste in - editing that to make more sense now

Comment: What's the advantage of doing `logmsg = ...` instead of doing an explicit function call like `logging.info(...)`…? What problem does your custom logger solve that the standard `logging` module doesn't?

Comment: Thats actually valid - I was writing the logger since I wasn't sure how else to log; thanks for the pointer! I shall look into the logging module and figure out how to use that.
But I don't understand how to make an explicitly function like the one you mentioned using codecs and such - should I open the file that I am logging to every time and then log messages? That seems wrong cause the whole log is open all the time and I keep writing to it whenever seems a more reasonable approach (at least to me)

Comment: The `logging` module takes care of that. You can configure it many different ways; to output to a specific file, or multiple files, or stdout (the default), and many other things. You won't be opening files manually at all when using `logging`.

Comment: Fixed it with the logging module! any idea why the code isn't working as planned though?